# Debug Facebook Meta Tags In Body

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

A few days ago I do not share the image well in facebook . The debug provides as follows : Errors That Must Be Fixed
Body Meta Tags In Your page has meta tags in the body Instead of the head . This May be Because your HTML was malformed And They fell lower in the parse tree .
Please fix este order for the tags to be usable.

the web is http://mundoentrenamiento.com

I guess there are some fragment in spoiling any code .

Help please .

Answer (score 1):

This error message is correct. When you input your URL into the Debugger, there is a link that shows you what the scraper sees from your page:

[image: Link from OG Debugger]

You can also access this directly with: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=[URL]. In your case, it would be https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmundoentrenamiento.com%2F

The link above shows that your page does not have head specified. The OG meta tags annotated on that page are inside the body element.

**What you currently have:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<meta property="og:locale" content="es_ES">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Mundo Entrenamiento | El deporte bajo">
<meta property="og:description" content="Revista en l&iacute.">
</body>
```

**What it should be:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:locale" content="es_ES">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Mundo Entrenamiento | El deporte bajo">
<meta property="og:description" content="Revista en l&iacute.">
</head>
<body> ... </body>
```

Comment: But it's a lie , I have the goal in the < head> look at the source code.
The strange thing is that if you look at the web with chrome element inspector leaves everything inside <body >

But if you look at the web with firefox element inspector leaves everything inside <head >

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post to say I have the same issue, so you didn't imagine it...but then i spotted what the mistake was in my case.

Within the head section I had previously commented out a line of code using the  suffix. It seems when i removed this comment I accidentally left the --> suffix in place, which was confusing the facebook debug page (interesting the code did still appear in the correct order with Chrome 'view source').

I used Notepad++ as my editor and its syntax highlighting didn't make this typo stand out enough for me to see at first.

Obviously I cannot see your html source, so don't know if this is the same reason for your error, but hopefully it gives you a clue what sort of things to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problem with facebook Debug/Scarper !

I spent about 4 hours to understand where is a problem !

The solution was simple.

Before try to do any changes with **internal** code/encoding, check this !

1. Open your file/s in **Notepad++**
2. Click to -> **Encode in UTF-8** instead of **Encode in UTF-8-BOM**
3. Save it.

[image]